# Splitting a string into multiple lines and write to file

Tags: perl, file

With Ensembl [API](http://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/Doxygen/core-api/classBio_1_1EnsEMBL_1_1Slice.html#a2423a9c5ed791e6e5fb3b9e659553d1a), there is a `seq()` method which prints a sequence in one line (1xN characters). The length of the sequence may be long (order of 10K). So, I want to split the string for every 100 characters. Currently, to write into a file, I use

```
my $outfilename = $row;
open(my $ofh, '>', $outfilename) or die "Could not open file '$outfilename' $!";
print $ofh $gene->seq();
```

Where `$gene` has been defined in the code.

How can I do that?

Comment: Here is an example using regex: `perl -E '$_ = "0123" x 10; say for /.{3}/g'`. You can use the `substr` function also

Comment: Can you explain more? is that a post process fro bash?

Comment: if that is a post process, how can I pass the output file name to this comand?

Comment: I assumed you wanted to write the substrings to the file. The command I showed can be implemented in your Perl script if you like. Just save `$gene->seq()` to a string first. Then split the string, and then write the substrings to the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easiest using `unpack`

```
open my $ofh, '>', $outfilename or die qq{Could not open file "$outfilename" for output: $!};

print $ofh "$_\n" for unpack '(A100)*', $gene->seq;
```

Comment: Or s: `print $ofh $gene->seq =~ s/\G.{100}\K/\n/gr;` (untested)

Answer (score 0):

```
my $outfilename = $row;
open(my $ofh, '>', $outfilename) or die "Could not open file '$outfilename' $!";
{
  my $gene_seq =  $gene->seq();
  my @chunks = $gene_seq =~ /(.{1,100})/sg; # split $gene_seq into 100 chars chunks
  print $ofh join("\n",@chunks),"\n";
}
```

Comment: There is an unmatched `(` in your code. Is that `(.)`?

Comment: Using "regex by trial and error"!!! I removed `(`. I think it was a typo in yout answer. Is that correct?!

Comment: I often see the idiom `print join("\n", @chunks), "\n"` and personally think it's rather ugly. `print "$_\n" for @chunks` is more concise and much clearer, and uses a lot less memory.